# Error Adding Recipient with Custom Email Notfication

Tags: docusignapi

I'm attempting to add a recipient to a draft envelope and althought the recipient does get added I receive an error message related to the notification.  Could someone explain the USER_LACKS_RECIPIENTEMAILNOTIFICATION_PERMISSION error is exactly?

```
POST /restapi/v2/accounts/123456/envelopes/3a20bef6-0d88-431a-aaf1-e27baa9b59a6/recipients HTTP/1.1

{
"carbonCopies": [
{
  "email": "my@emailaddress.com",
  "name": "Mike",
  "accessCode": "xyz",
  "addAccessCodeToEmail": true,
  "emailNotification": {
    "emailBody": "Custom email message different than the envelope body",
    "emailSubject": "Custom email subject",
    "supportedLanguage": "en"
  },
  "inheritEmailNotificationChange": false,
  "note": "Sample note",
  "recipientId": "1",
  "routingOrder": "1"
}
]
}
```

And here is the response that I receive back:

```
{
"signers": [],
"agents": [],
"editors": [],
"intermediaries": [],
"carbonCopies": [
{
  "name": "Mike",
  "email": "my@emailaddress.com",
  "recipientId": "1",
  "accessCode": "xyz",
  "requireIdLookup": "false",
  "routingOrder": "1",
  "note": "Sample note",
  "status": "error",
  "emailNotification": {
    "emailSubject": "Custom email subject",
    "emailBody": "Custom email message different than the envelope body",
    "supportedLanguage": "en"
  },
  "errorDetails": {
    "errorCode": "USER_LACKS_RECIPIENTEMAILNOTIFICATION_PERMISSION",
    "message": "Account or user does not have permission to set recipient email notifications."
  }
}
],
"certifiedDeliveries": [],
"inPersonSigners": [],
"recipientCount": "1"
}
```

The only permission setting that I can see might pertain to this is the following, but I can not change it's value.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to get around this issue is to not supply the ""supportedLanguage" property for the recipient. This is a feature that will need to be turned on for your sending user in order to use it.

Comment: Yep that works.  So could you explain the usage scenario for supportedLanguage?  The API definition describes the enums values but it is unclear to me where you might use this.  Is DocuSign trying to detect the user's locale and respond with appropriate messaging?  Auto translation services?  Appreciate some further insight.

Answer (score 0):

Check the "Reminders & Expirations" section to make sure you don't have the "Do NOT allow users to override these settings" setting checked?

[image]
[image]

Comment: That check box is not checked for me.